# How to determine when component ready in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

For example I have component with internal dom-repeat template. I need to know when all internal elements ready and then do some actions. But ready and attached handlers fires before internal templates ready. How can I do that right? Thank you!

```
  <template>
    <div class="b-item-content">     
      <span class="b-item-content-theme">[[subject]]</span>
      <span class="b-item-separator">[[separator]]</span>
      <span class="b-item-content-text">[[snippet]]</span>
      <div class="b-item-attachments">
      <div>{{attachments}}</div>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[attachments]]">
          <!--[[_constructAttachment(item)]]-->
          <attachment-item item="[[item]]"></attachment-item>
        </template>
      </div>    
    </div>     
  </template>
```

The main question.. If I have an element with 100 internal custom elements that have bindings with my parent element and model of parent element has changed. So how can I catch time when all internal custom elements rendered itself?? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This maybe will help you:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
  // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
  console.log('Components are ready');
});`
```

[Here](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponentsready) and [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#polymer-ready) you will find information about it.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't help when my data binding updates

Comment: To listen data's changes you must use an array observer.

Comment: Is there any methods to catch 1 event when all internal custom elements stamped it's html and main custom element ready to work?